# How to give package names to django javascript_catalog view?

Tags: django

From django documentation:

> js_info_dict = {
>       'packages': ('your.app.package',), }
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog',
>   js_info_dict), )
>
> Each string in packages should be in
>   Python dotted-package syntax (the same
>   format as the strings in
>   INSTALLED_APPS) and should refer to a
>   package that contains a locale
>   directory.

It says "a package that contains a locale directory." , but i created translation files with djangoadmin.py makemessages -a and it creates locale just inside project directory. Not under any of my application directories. And i try to set packages as

> js_info_dict = {
>       'packages': ('my_project_dir',), }

Apparently that's not working for me. Every string from django domain gets translated but i get an empty translation catalog in javascript from javascript_catalog view. What am i missing here?

Comment: your question is very unclear.. you should provide more info

Comment: I have the same problem. I guess it's related with this bug http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5494

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to be sure that your js_info_dict is like this:

```
js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('my_project_name',),
}
```

And as @daonb suggested, add 'my_project_name' to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Make sure that you compile your messages like this:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -a -d djangojs
```

That's all!

I don't know why Django doesn't have that information into its documentation. I could find the solution with using these articles below:

http://www.aminche.com/blog/2010/07/06/playground-editor
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5494
http://osdir.com/ml/django-users/2010-04/msg00231.html

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was to call django-admin.py makemessages in the top level of project directory. That created translation catalogs for the entrire project. But it turns out that javascript catalog needs locale directories on django app dir basis. So after using

1. cd /home/my_project/my_app
2. mkdir locale
3. django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l en

It creates translation strings just for my_app dir and I can use :

js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('my_app',),
}

Comment: You're welcome. Normally it has to support application locales. So, it's not your fault, it's a bug: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5494

Cheers!

Comment: A note from the far future world of 2023: js_info_dict is no longer a thing in django. This accepted answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding 'my_project_dir' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. What do you mean with that adding project name to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yeah, it has to solve the problem, but it doesn't. http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/5494/root-locale-js-catalog.diff

Comment: The patch on that ticket is cleaner than adding the project to INSTALLED_APP. Still, it solved the problem in my project.

Answer (score 0):

For others with my particular case, js messages are generated and compiled OK but not rendered in templates or pages when you use i18n language urls.

This is because javascript catalog should be added to i18n urls patterns, not to normal patterns.

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict), )
```

=>

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('', (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict), )
```