# Empty catalog when internationalizing JavaScript code

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'm trying to set up [Internationalization of JavaScript code in my Django application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code).

My Django app has a `locale` subdirectory with a properly generated `djangojs.po` file. The package definition is as follows:

```
# urls.py
js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('my_project',),
}
```

`./manage.py makemessages` worked well as the `.po` file contains all the to-be-translated strings but no JavaScript string ever gets translated on the website and the catalog is always empty.

Answer (score 6):

I also had some problems with. This is how it works for me:

Add this to yr root urls.py:

```
js_info_dict = { 'domain': 'djangojs',
                 'packages': ('YOUR_PROJECT_NAME',), }


urlpatterns = patterns('',                   

    #enable using translation strings in javascript
    #source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n
    (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),

)
```

In JS files use:

```
var somevar = gettext('Text to translate');
```

To compile django translation files: In a shell/terminal run from the project root (where 'apps', 'settings', etc lie):

```
#for "normal django files" (.py, .html):
django-admin.py makemessages --locale=de
#for javascript files. source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3571954/268125
django-admin.py makemessages -a -d djangojs --locale=de
#to compile the translation files to machine code
django-admin.py compilemessages --locale=de
```

Comment: Still had to add my project to INSTALLED_APPS. (which I don't like)

Comment: It still does not work for me. And it seems that 'djangojs' is the default domain. No need to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

i added my_project to INSTALLED APPS in settings.py and that seemed to do the trick

Comment: I already have "my_project" in my_project's INSTALLED APPS in settings.py and still the catalog is empty. Might you have an idea as to what else needs to be done?

Comment: I've found out what went wrong for me. I had put my po files under <project root>/conf/locale when it should have been <project root>/locale .